# Best practices for creating multiple web app instance

Tags: web-applications, multiple-instances

I would like to know your opinion on the ideal approach of developing an multiple web app instance for SaaS.

Just to give out a rough idea on what i am trying to do is:

Suppose there is a web app, let say HR application (i.e. OrangeHRM). Where i as the service provider would have more than one clients.

In my application, it could have multiple users with different roles and so on, so forth.

What would be the ideal way to implement this in terms:

- modularity (adding new modules in the future)
- confidentiality
- scalability (i am not sure with this regards)

I have thought of using different approach such as:

- I would have multiple copies of my apps (think of having multiple root folders within your public_html folder). This way, my server would essentially run the same applications to gether.
- I would have multiple database schemas, one for each client. I would do this so that data between clients do not get mixed up together.
- Other suggestions are welcome....

So, bottom line is i would like to have multiple instances of application which shares (or could partially shares) the same code. I would prefer that data of one client be separated to another.

I would preferably use the following language / framework in collaboration with MySQL as my data store.

- Django, Phyton, HTML, CSS, jQuery Laravel, PHP, HTML, CSS, jQuery

Thanks

Comment: Maybe, this forum reply may help: http://forums.devshed.com/mysql-help-4/practice-opinions-multi-user-multi-organisation-web-app-812530.html

Comment: Hey @Jemery , I am currently faced with the same dilemma. What kind of solution did you end up using? Thanks.

Comment: @MyNameIsZero i ended up using different services (you can call it as apps). What i did is i have an account database, this basically stores all the accounts. Then i the actual app itself has its own database, which is automactially generated once a particular user has created an account.